# Curl send dir to remote samba without password

Tags: curl, libcurl, samba

Hi i want send dir to remote samba folder.
Remote folder is public without password.
How i can do it ?
I try:

```
curl --upload-file mydir -U %  smb://nas/Public/
curl: (67) Login denied

curl --upload-file mydir -U " "%" "  smb://nas/Public/
curl: (67) Login denied
```